# Calling a method on an object after it was created in Switch Case in C++

Tags: c++

I have created an object using new in a switch case.  The object is assigned to an element of an array of pointers.  While in the case I am able to call a method on that object, but outside the case it seems I cannot. It just doesn't do it.  I have a function to set the elements of the object which I can call while within the case, but outside of the switch case I don't seem to be able to call that element with a method to show the contents of the object.  I supposed there might be a scope problem here, but the array is declared outside of the switch case.

Here is a code snippet:

```
int main(void)
{
    employee * pc[MAX];
    showmenu();
    int choice;
    cin >> choice;
    int j = 0;
    while(true)
    {
         switch(choice)
            {
                case 1 :
                    {
                         cout << "j = " << j << endl;
                         employee * bee = new employee();
                         pc[j] = bee;
                         pc[j]->SetAll();
                         delete bee;
                         break;
                    }

                case 2 :
                    {
                         cout << "j = " << j << endl;
                         manager * see = new manager();
                         pc[j] = see;
                         pc[j]->SetAll();
                         delete see;
                         break;
                    }

                case 3 :
                    {
                         cout << "j = " << j << endl;
                         fink * dee = new fink();
                         pc[j] = dee;
                         pc[j]->SetAll();
                         delete dee;
                         break;
                    }

                case 4 :
                    {
                         cout << "j = " << j << endl;
                         highfink * eee = new highfink();
                         pc[j] = eee;
                         pc[j]->SetAll();
                         delete eee;
                         break;
                    }


                default :   cout << "That's not a choice.\n";
            }
            showmenu();
            cin >> choice;
            j++;
            if (j>=MAX || choice == 5)
                break;


    }

    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
    {
        cout << "I made it into the for loop " << i << " times" << endl;
        pc[i]->ShowAll();
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `pc[j] = bee;` This saves the `bee` pointer into the array. `delete bee;` This deletes the `bee` pointer, so `pc[j]` now points to an object that no longer exists.

Comment: You should refactor `cout << "j = "` to before the `switch` statement; or use a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an explanation of what the code actually doing:

First, you declared a pointer to the object then you take a copy of that pointer (an address), and then you deleted that pointer.

So you have an address to memory but you are not allowed to access it as you deleted the pointer (dangling pointer).

This is a common mistake especially when you are working with functions and then returning a pointer.

What I recommend is as follows:

```
cout << "j = " << j << endl;
pc[j] = new employee();
pc[j]->SetAll();
break;
```

Comment: Thanks!  Seems kind of obvious now.

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple: in your `case` clauses, you immediately destroy the object using `delete`.

That is why you can not call any of its methods later.

Notice, that what you are putting in the array is only a pointer to the object.
The exact same pointer stored in `bee` variable.

Once you call `delete` on it, it becomes invalid.
You are not creating a copy of the object!

Answer (score 0):

Your `delete XXX;` statements delete the objects that were assigned to elements of `pc`.

Answer (score 0):

```
employee * bee = new employee();
```

Ok, dynamical memory allocation for an employee class object. Now on the heap memory
segment we have an employee class object stored. Address of that object has been
stored to the pointer named bee. ( Read/Google for the 'new' operator dynamic
memory allocation, heap memory segment for the understanding of this. It is not so difficult. )

```
 pc[j] = bee;
```

Pointers equality! Now pc[j] and bee are pointing to the same object which is previously created. With this statement two pointers are pointing to the same object on the heap memory segment so you can destroy that object with each one of them !
Very dangerous situation. This equality is calling your program to crush!

```
pc[j]->SetAll();
```

Nothing special. Method call...
But here comes the problem.

```
delete bee;
```

This statement is destroying your previously created employee class object.
You ask yourself how ? Because of this
**delete bee; <=> delete p[j];** because `bee` and `p[j]` are pointing to the same object and later when you do

```
for(int i = 0; i < than...' i++)
```

`p[i] ->doSomething` you ask the dead object to do something...

That's why your code crashes.
To fix this you can comment `delete bee;` but I am not familiar with your program
so memory leak you tried to avoid with the `delete bee;` line will have to be done using an Class Destructor.